How can I extract different colored lines or parts of lines from a diagram into separate data?
For example, how can I extract the black, red, blue parts of a line, and another green line in the diagram below as four separate data sets?
Here is my attempt and code, but it hasn't been successful.
I would appreciate any help, thank you!
SetOptions[Plot, ColorFunctionScaling -> False];

colorfun = 
  Function[{x, y}, If[Cos[x] > 0, Red, If[x y < 0, Blue, Black]]];
tend = 10;
fig = Show[{Plot[Sin[Cos[t^2]], {t, 0, tend}, 
    ColorFunction -> colorfun], 
   Plot[Cos[Sin[t^2]], {t, 0, tend}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thin, Green, Dashed}]}, PlotRange -> All]

dat = Cases[InputForm@fig, Line[x_] :> x, ∞];

ListPlot[Evaluate@dat]



You're using InputForm and Evaluate blindly. InputForm is only for displaying the inputform in frontend, it won't influence the FullForm of code. Evaluate is only for functions with attribute adjusting the evaluation order e.g. HoldAll, HoldFirst, etc., ListPlot doesn't have such attributes, so Evaluate won't have any effect. These are not causing problem in your code, though.
The root of the problem is, the colors of line segments colored by ColorFunction option are not specified by the Graphics[{color, Line[...]},...] syntax, it's specified by VertexColors option of a GraphicsComplex[...] expression. (This is not too hard to notice by observing the fig by pressing Ctrl+Shift+i, or using InputForm, or using ShortInputForm. )
So a possible solution is:
dat = Cases[fig, GraphicsComplex[a_, __] :> a, Infinity][[1]];

color = Cases[fig, (VertexColors -> a_List) :> a, ∞][[1]];

lst = dat[[Flatten@Position[color, #]]] & /@ {Black, Blue, Red};

(* Find out those not colored by VertexColors: *)
datrest = 
  Complement[#, dat] & /@ Cases[fig, Line[a_] :> a, ∞] // 
   DeleteCases[{}];

ListPlot[Join[lst, datrest], PlotStyle -> {Black, Blue, Red, Green}]



Thanks. Your explanation is so clear as always. Perfect! Have a nice day :)

@xinxinguo You should really put a bit more effort in understanding the core language… I tried explaining Evaluate and InputForm a bit more in the answer, have a look.

You're absolutely right, I will reinforce my study of the basics of Mathematica. Thanks for your advice! :)
